# time complexity of radix sort including duplicate keys

Tags: data-structures

imagine that we have an array including n distinct integers in the range of `[1,n^6]` and we want to sort it by radix sort which uses an auxiliary algorithm with `\theta f(n)` time complexity.
I know that the time complexity of radix sort would be `theta(n^6f(n))`
but if we have some duplicate keys, what the time complexity is? can we guess or not?
I would be appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about mathematics and not a programming question within the scope defined in [help/on-topic]. You may be able to ask this question on [Math StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) (see tags [asymptotics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/asymptotics/info) and [computational-complexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-complexity/info)) or [CS StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to check their question guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand where you're getting `theta(n^6)` from. A radix sort is best used when the maximum size of each data point is small compared to the size of the data set, because it puts each element into a bucket, and repeats this operation for each digit (in its base) of the largest element. When the largest element's length is smaller than log(N), the radix sort can outperform comparison-based sorting.

Take an example, base 10, sorting N numbers, where the largest element is 999. This requires three passes over the N numbers (3 is the length of 999 in base 10, equal to `floor(log_10(999))+1`). If we say that one pass of the algorithm takes `f(N)` time, then the algorithm takes `3*f(N)` time to execute.

In your example, say the radix sort's base is N, your largest input is going to be 7 (`floor(log_N(N^6)+1 = 7`), so the algorithm will need to take 7 passes over the data set. If I'm understanding you correctly, this will take `theta(7*f(n))` time, if each pass is characterized by `theta(f(n))`.

When duplicates are added, the algorithm can be modified to count elements that match rather than sorting them individually. The worst case remains `O(log(MAX_VALUE)*f(n))`, if there are very few duplicates. The best case is `omega(N)`, if all values are the same, because the first pass will find all elements are duplicates and then you can have the algorithm stop.

Because the worst and best cases are so different, theta-notation no longer applies.

For the average case, basically you have a first pass over the data, counting duplicates. From that point on, you perform a normal radix sort on the unique values, so your algorithm will be `O(N + log(MAX_VALUE)*f(UNIQUE_VALUES))`, where MAX_VALUE is the largest input, and UNIQUE_VALUES is the number of non-duplicates.

Ordinarily, we say `MAX_VALUE := N` and `UNIQUE_VALUES := N`, because we can't make strong guarantees about them in general. This means the algorithm is overall `O(N * log(N))`. If you know specific formulas for them (as you do in your example where MAX_VALUE := N^6), then you can get more specific.

Comment: it should be 'theta(nf(n))'. imagine that n=2 so that we have 2 keys in the range of [1,64], so ech key must have at most 2 digit.